# Getting a block of text using Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Basically what I'm attempting to do is input the song and artist in the url which will then bring me to the page with the song's lyrics I'm then going to find the correct way to get those lyrics. I'm new to using Jsoup. So far the issue I've been having is I can't figure out the correct way to get the lyrics. I've tried getting the first "div" after the "b" but it doesn't seem to work out the way I plan.

```
public static void search() throws MalformedURLException {

    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    String artist;
    String song;

    artist = search.nextLine();
    artist = artist.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Artist saved");
    song = search.nextLine();
    song = song.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Song saved");
    artist = artist.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(artist);
    song = song.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(song);
    try {
        Document doc;
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/"+artist+"/"+song+".html").get();
        System.out.println(doc.title());

        for(Element element : doc.select("div")) {

            if(element.hasText()) {
                System.out.println(element.text());
                break;
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please put just a *little* more effort into your question. All you've posted is a "want"' and an unexplained code dump, which to be bluntly honest is a bit on the lazy side. If you spend just a little more time describing what problems your code is having, what specific things you are unclear of, we likely can give you a much better answer. I'm looking forward to checking your your edited question. Good luck! Also, please remember that we are all volunteers, so your efforts to make it easy to help you are **much** appreciated!

Comment: Note, if this were my project, I'd do some in-depth study the source code of the web pages that I'm trying to extract, and then try incrementally to isolate the information that I desire.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is consistent or not in all song pages, but in the page you have shown, the lyrics appear with the div element whose first attribute is margin. If this is consistent, you could try something on the order of...

```
Elements eles = doc.select("div[style^=margin]");         
System.out.println(eles.html());
```

---

Or if it's always the 6th div element with lyrics, you could use that:

```
Elements eles = doc.select("div");
if (eles.size() >= 6) {
    System.out.println(eles.get(6).html());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm on my way to getting it the way I want.